# I would like to access my localhost files with an ftp programme

Tags: apache2, ftp

I have installed an apache2 server and installed php and everything else I need to run a website from my laptop, however, when I try to access it with CrossFTP with the following settings

[image: Image 1]

I get the following results:

[image]

I do not have a firewall set up and I get the same response with IP address 127.0.0.1

Can anyone explain what's happening, and what I should try next?

Comment: Does it work if you use 127.0.0.1 for the host? Could you also clarify whether you have created any firewall rules in Ubuntu? It may also work if you use just FTP instead of FTP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, No fire walls and the same problem with 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting using SSH, not FTP. This has nothing to do with your Apache or ftp server. You must ensure that the ssh server on your computer works and allows you to log in. See for example this link: http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/05/ubuntu-ssh-how-to-enable-secure-shell-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Sorted just before I go into hospital!